# PHP unit test - How to fake a vendor Guzzle request

Tags: php, web-services, testing, automated-tests, guzzle

I'm trying to make a test that involves 2 services on PHP.

The internal logic of my service 'A' needs to send a message to service "B". I do not have B configured, so it will always respond with error on a testing environment, however, i don't need to know what 'B' does, i just need to know that after 'B' gave a 200 response, the callback on service 'A' saves some data on my DB.

The communication between services is handled by a private vendor package that uses Guzzle under the hood. The problem i found, is that i cannot seem to be able to use Guzzle Mock or STack without touching the vendor's source code right?

So, is the best solution creating a fake api that always responds 200 to my requests on the same ip:port of the real "B" service??

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe expand on "use Guzzle Mock or STack without touching the vendor's source code". Not sure I follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand you right but it should be easy to solve this.

Create a stub from Service B class and configure the method called by Service A:

```
$serviceBStub = $this->createStub(ServiceB::class);
$serviceBStub->method('yourRequest')->willReturn(200);
```

After you call the method on Service A you can check the result on your DB:

```
$this->assertEquals('foo', $db->find(1)->getTitle());
```

Or you can use a mock instead:

```
$dbMock = $this->createMock(Db::class);
$dbMock->expects($this->once())
                 ->method('create')
                 ->with($this->equalTo('something'));
```

Source: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/9.3/test-doubles.html

Comment: I decided to use mock. I had trouble because service A was creating it's own instance of service B instead of receiving a parameter, so i couln't apply the mock. I'm rewriting a few bits to support it. Thanks.